# How to check if a button was clicked in a different class in java?

Tags: java, button, android-intent, android-studio, onclicklistener

I have 4 button in 1 (Class A) of my classes. All buttons lead to the same class (Class B), however, I want to set an if restriction depending on what button is clicked in Class A. Here is a sample of my code.

I want to change the value of qid depending on what option is clicked. For example, if the clicked was 5, the if statement should be "qid > 5". If button clicked was 10, the if statement should be "qid > 10". I am not sure if you can do this, but I think if we assign a number to each button that gets transferred to Class B, the the If statements could become "If (code=1 || qid > 5).
Again, I'm not certain how to approach this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ToClass.class);
i.putExtra("button", "5");
startActivity(i);
```

Receive:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int buttonValue = Integer.valueOf(intent.getExtras().getString("button"));
if (qid > buttonValue ) {
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help!